# Literal as part of generic type -- python typing

Tags: python, python-typing

Say I want to design an `Array` datatype in Python. It is intended to house a fixed size list of a particular type.

```py
T = typing.TypeVar('T')
class Array(typing.Generic[T]):
  l: list[T]
  s: int
```

so the type hint would be something like:

```py
fixed_size_array: Array[int]
```

What I want to do is include the length of the `Array` in the type hint, e.g.:

```py
fixed_size_array_of_five_ints: Array[int, 5]
fixed_size_array_of_four_ints: Array[int, 4]
```

I can change the implementation of `Array` as the only requirement I have is a type hint of `Array[int, 5]` or something which includes the literal/constant size.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure the type system supports this, but what do you hope to accomplish with it?

Comment: You already have the attibute `s`. What would adding redundant information do to help?

Comment: @MadPhysicist well, in principle, the type system could use this information to catch errors statically, imagine something like a ndarray with shape, and a type system that supports that, conceivably, it would be able to statically analyze and catch a bunch of errors due to shape mismatch. But I'm pretty sure nothing like that exists for Python

Comment: If it's a fixed size iterable it usually makes more sense to use a `tuple` or a subclass of it. You can type-hint, say, a 5 element tuple using `tuple[int, int, int, int, int]`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#special-forms Note that tuples are immutable, but in your case they have to be that way for the linter to be able to infer types anyway.

Comment: @Selcuk I suspect that actually may be the OP's use-case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is correct -- I want the type system to check the size.

Comment: @JohnDemme can you elaborate on exactly what you are expecting? Maybe some examples of how you imagine this would work?

Comment: @selcuk I want to support arbitrarily large arrays like `Array[int, 1024]`, so using a tuple is really not feasible. The use case here is hardware design/modeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Literal[...]:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')
S = typing.TypeVar('S')

class Array(typing.Generic[T, S]):
  l: list[T]
  s: S
  def __init__(self, s: S):
    self.l = []
    #...
    self.s = s

def typed_array_op(a: T, b: T) -> T:
  return some_func(a, b)

#...

a2: Array[int, Literal[2]]
b2: Array[int, Literal[2]]
a3: Array[int, Literal[3]]

a2 = array(2)
a3 = array(2) # mypy error

typed_array_op(a2, b2)
typed_array_op(a2, a3) # mypy error
```