# python subclass list and matching generic

Tags: python, generics, subclass, mypy, typing

I found out its able to subclass in this way or through throw `__new__` with no problem, but type checking.

```py
class a(tuple):
    pass

print(a((1, 2, 3)))  # <---- ( 1, 2, 3 )

b: tuple[int, int, int] = a((1, 2, 3))  # <--- Error
# Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "a", variable has type "Tuple[int, int, int]")

c: tuple = a((1, 2, 3))  # <--- Ok  

d: tuple[int, int, int] = (1, 2, 3)  # <--- Ok
```

The same way when you subclass list will work.

```py
    class a( list[ T ] ) 
 
        def __init__(self, * pax : T  )  : pass

    b : list[ int ] = a( 1, 2 ) # <--- Ok  

    c = a[ int ]( 1, 2 ) # <--- Ok
```

How can I subclass tuple correctly? thank you for your advise.

Comment: @j1-lee same. BTW, I recommend @Micah to use `Tuple[int, ...]` or `Tuple[int, int, int]` rather than `tuple[int, int, int]` by `from typing import Tuple`.

Comment: Python 3.10.5, using Tuple gets the same mypy error

Comment: weird. I got no error in 3.10.6. See https://codepaste.xyz/posts/yNMuXCiujJqobjQgMZcL

Comment: Its mypy error, will this codepaste check it well?

Comment: @hide1nbush `b: Tuple[int, ...] = a((1, 2, 3))` is not the same as `b: tuple[int, int, int] = a((1, 2, 3))`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287623/a-way-to-subclass-namedtuple-for-purposes-of-typechecking help?

Comment: @metatoaster yes. But Micah seems still getting error using `Tuple`

Comment: @hide1nbush its mypy error, I edited a example with sub List the same way, will not raise error. Can you help?

Comment: @hide1nbush To be clear `Tuple[int, ...]` will not result in an error, but explicit number of elements without the ellipsis will.  I am pointing out how you have changed the code and thus you failed to reproduce the error with the correct, affected code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I cant find similarities, can you give me an easier example maybe?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mypy; I quite like dynamic typing. That was my best attempt to find a related question by searching with appropriate terms.

Comment: Regarding ability to preserve type parameters on subclass (like `a[int,int,str]`), i.e. variadic generics, see [discussion in comments to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73838487/how-to-pass-generic-through-type-alias). The proposed answer won't work here (since you need a subclass and not an alias), but PEP646 discussed there is your (only?) way to go, still lacking `mypy` support.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are being confounded by has nothing to do with subclassing but has everything due to how mypy assumes *any* sequence passed as an argument to any `tuple` and its subclasses by their name (e.g. `tuple((item, item, ..., item))`, as opposed to the Python tuple syntax `(item, item, ..., item,)`) to have the signature `Tuple[Any, ...]` (as that is the type signature for the default `tuple` constructor).  Consider the following code example:

```
one_tuple: tuple[int] = tuple((1,))
answer: tuple[int] = (1,)
print(one_tuple == answer)
```

Running the above code with `python` will produce the output `True`, which is what is expected.  However, `mypy` will produce the following error message:

```
onetuple.py:1: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Given that it is impossible to use Python's standard tuple syntax to produce instances of its subclass (as it *always* produce a `tuple`), any subclasses of `tuple` (e.g. `class MyTuple(tuple): ...`) would then therefore not be able to satisfy any `Tuple[T]` where `T` is not a sequence of variable length.

While the following assertion is not stated in the question, if you know for sure your `tuple` subclass is going to have some finite length, this may be a suitable workaround:

```
class MyTuple(tuple[int, int, int]):
    pass

mytuple: tuple[int, int, int] = MyTuple((1, 2, 3))
```

In this case, `mypy` will not generate any validation errors.

As an addendum, with the introduction of [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) - Variadic Generics, this may become possible starting from Python 3.11, however `mypy` has no support for this quite yet (see GitHub issue [python/mypy#12840](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12840), under new typing features, PEP 646 - as of 2022-10-14 no sub-issue has been tracked there yet), and `pyright` and `pyre` doesn't appear to correctly check the statement `one_tuple: tuple[int] = tuple((1, 2,))` as invalid, thus I end my further effort here for now given that I am unsure if it does actually correctly support PEP 646.

Comment: Yes, indeed this way works, if I want to become able to assign different number of generics dynamically like tuple itself. What should I do?

Comment: @Micah You basically have to override the `__new__` method for you `tuple` subclass with the intended signature (i.e. number of arguments), but then you will run into this [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8957) that has not been fixed.

Comment: In his case, using tuple.__new__( cls , iterable ), can resolve the problem. But I think my question is more related to how can I assign dynamic number of generic.

Comment: this example can give us options to assign same type, but tuple can have different types, how can we do it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529338/literal-as-part-of-generic-type-python-typing

Comment: I would just use the default `tuple[...]` signature and reserve subclasses for concrete one-off alias of some defined `tuple[...]`.  Honestly, what you are asking for is currently not possible to be validated/expressed in Python/mypy. Try reporting what you want as an issue on the [mypy issue tracker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/).

Comment: Alternatively, rather than subclassing, compose a new class that has a specific `tuple` type signature for instances of that new class.